# Java - How to create an array list using a contructor from another class that sets the values

Tags: java

Im trying to add a complete list of cards. I'm trying to add the 'cards' using the cards constructor using the array list and i want to input the suit and number.

In "Card" class:

```
Card(Suit suit, int rank){ 
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank; 
}
```

In "Deck" Class:

```
Deck(){ 
    ArrayList cards = new ArrayList(52);

    for (int i=0; i<=13; i++){ 
        cards.add(Card(SPADES,i));  //Trying to use the constuctor from the other class
    }
}
```

When doing the above, the "SPADES" is underlined and it says cannot find symbol.

Comment: Where is `SPADES` actually defined (as `int`)? Do you have `Enum` or `static final int` variables?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm assuming that it is an enum as the constructor for card takes a `Suit`.  But I cannot be sure.

Comment: Also, the better way is not to use `raw` types, instead use `ArrayList<Card> cards = Arraylist<>(52);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Suit.SPADES` not just `SPADES`. You must use the new keyword before Card, i.e.

```
new Card(...)
```

And you can use nested for loops with your enums.

```
for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { 
    cards.add(new Card(suit, i));
  }
}
```

`Suit.values()` returns and array of all the enums held by Suit.

As a side note, I would recommend not using int to represent rank but rather to create a separate Rank enum, one that holds a value (or two if aces can hold more than one value such as in blackjack), that holds rank names for jack, king and queen.

Also, what does an i = 0 mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. You call a constructor with the `new` keyword.
2. Assuming `SPADES` is in an enum, you must access it with `Suit.SPADES`, not just `SPADES`.
3. You may have visibility issues (though if the two classes are in the same package you should be fine), so you may want to make it `public Card(Suit suit, int rank)` and `public Deck()`.  This might not be required but it is a good idea.

To correct your `Deck` class:

```
public Deck(){ 
    ArrayList cards = new ArrayList(52);

    for (int i=0; i<=13; i++){ 
        cards.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES,i));
    }
}
```